# broken file icons when I access a directory via wamp server

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I just installed wamp server so I can start with laravel. 
**Problem 1**(resolved , see Filipe's answer)
When I access a directory named `php` in `www` folder of `wamp` it gives me files with broken icons [link](http://prntscr.com/7r0fus).
I have tried changing `port 80` to `8080` in `httpd.conf` file but it did not resolve the issue. 
**Problem 2**(see my answer)
I think when skype is running `wamp server icon` does not become green.
**Problem 3**
I have a directory in `www` folder named `php` when I try to open it from `wamp icon->left click->My Projects->php` , `wamp` opens it as `php/` but `browser` gives the error
`This webpage is not available`.
Any help would be appreciated.
I changed these lines in `httpd.conf` file from

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

**UPDATE**
I have xampp installed too in `c:/xampp` , does it has to do something if `wamp` server is not coming online or I am unable to access files ?

Comment: Did you change the wamp server directory?

Comment: @FilipeFerreira sorry ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems quite a known problem with xampp what you need to do is go to your config file and find the following line:

Edit the this file :  **httpd-autoindex.conf**

```
Alias /icons/ "/apache/icons/"

 <Directory "/apache/icons/">
```

So it looks like this

```
Alias /icons/ "c:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/icons/"

     <Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/icons/">
```

After make sure you they are pointing to the correct filepath.
`Note:`-`httpd-autoindex.conf` is located in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra`

To the secound error on your browser write:

**localhost:8080**

And it should work also change the **http.conf** file instead of saying 80 to say 8080:

```
   <VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

**Restart APACHE.**

Comment: which config file ? and can you please address my second problem too?

Comment: do i need to change the second line to `8080` too ?  `ServerName localhost:8080
80HostnameLookups Off`

Comment: @Adamnick no your server name should just be the url the port is set here:  <VirtualHost *:8080>

Comment: i could not find any line exactly like this `<VirtualHost *:8080>` in `httpd.conf` file .

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid Command '80HostnameLookups' , perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`
I got this error when I debug the issue (wamp server was not going online -**Problem 2**) by the procedure defined here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416403/apache-wont-start-in-wamp) by @RiggsFolly.
Just comment the line `80HostnameLookups Off` by changing it to `#80HostnameLookups Off`.
This solution worked for me and `apache` starts running.