# my wamp 3.0.6 is not starting giving apache error.Can someone pleaserecommend?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, frameworks

I want to install latest PHP 7 version so I was installing it in my vista homepremium 32 bit. But it is giving Apache error. My Apache is not working. Can someone please help or recommend me another version for PHP 7 so as I can install Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue in the httpd.conf or any files included by it there are a couple of ways to find out what the problem is

First look at your `Windows Event Viewer`. Click on the `Windows` link in the left and menu and then `Applications`. Look for messages from Apache with the red error icon.

Secondly, open a command window, then CD into \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\bin, replace x,y with your actual version. Now you can run this command to get Apache(httpd) to vaidate the httpd.conf file.

```
httpd.exe -t
```

This should give errors with line numbers related to the http.conf file. It stops on the first error, so you will have to keep running it and fixing the error and then run it again until it gives the all OK message.

Original answer: [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416403/apache-wont-start-in-wamp)

Comment: it is not working cmd is giving - the system doesnot find the path specified

Comment: Check where wamp is installed on your pc and cd to that path, the path above might not be the same for everyone

Comment: Thanks Joppe but my path is also same i dont where m getting problem but I will try again

Comment: Hey Joppe I tried my path is CD\WAMP\BIN\APACHE\APACHE2.2.17. UPTO THIS it works and when m typing APACHE2.x.Y IT IS giving the path is not specified.

Comment: when you are in the APACHE2.2.17 folder, type cd bin. As you can see in my answer, the x.y stands for 2.17 (in this case)

Comment: HI i understand n i have used CD\WAMP\BIN\APACHE\APACHE2.2.17\BIN AND THEN ENTER ENTER ENTER     :D